# c# Regular Expression : Special characters: ~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?`€[]\;',./

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to check below mentioned special characters as well extended Latin characters in my data.

*Special characters*: ``` ~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?``€[]\;',./ ```

*Diacriticals*: `é, ö, ò, etc`

I have tried `[^a-z]`, but it does not work as I need, it also captures unwanted characters.

Could you please help me to suggest the correct regular expression?

Comment: Please provide more information. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET, you can use special character classes, too. The letters you provided come from `\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}` [Unicode character set](http://unicode-table.com/en/#latin-1-supplement).

The regex then can be

```
[\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?`€\[\]\\;',./]+
```

or

```
[\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{P}\p{S}]+
```

since the symbols you provided come from symbols and punctuation Unicode character sets.

Sample code to match single characters from the character class:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"[\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{P}\p{S}]");
var str = "~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?€[]\\;',./`éöò";
var all = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

Output (in VS2012):

[image]

Comment: Hello, I am also looking for regular expression for Valid price value like              100,100.00,and number should be without negative sign....is it possible using regular expression

Comment: @Rakesh: I do not know what exactly you are looking for. If it is live validation, then, it is not that easy since you'll have to use look-aheads. If not, it is really simple. BUT for price validation, I'd just use C# Decimal.TryParse() (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Please post your question, and you'll surely get an anwer.

Comment: Hello, Please find question related to price validations  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29415527/c-sharp-price-validation-using-regular-expression-other-way

Comment: Stribizhev: I more help I required which I posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29790137/c-sharp-regex-remove-string-which-developed-only-combination-of-special-charter