# C# Price Validation using regular expression other way

Tags: c#, .net, regex

As part of my work,I need to read price values from Excel sheet . I need to implement

- Prices: Non-numeric characters in Price not allowed
- price should be valid number for price like int,decimal,double etc like 10,10.00,10,233 valid, -10,-10.00,-10,2333.00 etc are invalid
- Prices: Price format (dots, comma's, decimals)
- Zero and negative price values are not allowed
- Need to check price value type (number type like int,float,decimal etc but will save in database in money format)

What datatype I should we choose for Price ? decimal or double or anyother ? In database I took database field type as money.

Comment: `Price format (dots, comma's, decimals)` what's that supposed to mean? Some cultures use comma to separate thousands, others use it as a decimal separator. Which do *you* mean?

Comment: `decimal` is *designed* to be used for money values - don't use IEEE-754 floating point values, as they do not represent an *exact* value: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: So, what's your question? The one in the title (*"I need a regular expression for..."*) or the one in the text (*"Which datatype should I choose for Price?"*)?

Comment: You must provide more examples, sample input, required output... Otherwise, it is difficult to help you and others having a similar problem.

Comment: Price format (dots, comma's, decimals): Yes you are right some culture are using different format so they can put prices value in that format. My question is "is these validation can be done by simply regular expression or or is there any other way". Client can put any kind of value for prices in any format (by mistake).So I need to validate those prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you need any regex if you just need to validate price numbers in C#.

I'd suggest using `Decimal` type, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c) you can find why. The `Decimal` class contains a static `TryParse` method that can be used to validate numbers as valid `decimal` numbers. Here is a slightly modified example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) (I decided to go with `InvariantCulture`, but it depends on whether your DB contains currencies in EN-US format or not):

```
var validated = false;
decimal number;
// Parse currency value using current culture. 
var value = "1,097.63";
var style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number;
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
if (!Decimal.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
    if (number > 0)    // Check if the value is not negative or zero
        validated = true;
```