# c# Regex- Remove string which developed only combination of special charter

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I am looking for regular expression by which I can ignore strings which is only combination of **All special charters**.

Example

```
List<string> liststr = new List<string>() { "a b", "c%d", " ", "% % % %" ,"''","&","''","'"}; etc...
```

I need result of this one

```
{ "a b", "c%d"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one :

```
.*[A-Za-z0-9].*
```

It matches at least one alphanumeric character. Doing this, it will take any string that is not only symbols/special chars. It does the output you want, see here : [demo](http://regexr.com/3as36)

Comment: its working for above example which i mentioned but for string "~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?€[]\\;',./`éöò" its not working  List<string> liststr = new List<string>() { "a b", "c%d", " ", "% % % %" ,"''","&","~!@©#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?€[]\\;',./`éöò"};

Comment: Strange, `\w` matches `_`.. Updated, @Rakesh

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, too, to match string without *any Unicode* letter:

```
var liststr = new List<string>() { "a b", "c%d", " ", "% % % %", "''", "&", "''", "'" };
var rx2 = @"^\P{L}+$";
var res2 = liststr.Where(p => !Regex.IsMatch(p, rx2)).ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

I also suggest creating the regex object as a `private static readonly` field, with `Compiled` option, so that performance is not impacted.

```
private static readonly Regex rx2 = new Regex(@"^\P{L}+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
... (and inside the caller)
var res2 = liststr.Where(p => !rx2.IsMatch(p)).ToList();
```

Comment: While this is an excellent answer, it seems OP considers most Unicode letters as special characters (see comments on my post). Otherwise, your answer is far superior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very simple regex like

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[% &']+$");
```

Where

- `[% &']` Is the list of special characters that you wish to include

**Example**

```
List<string> liststr = new List<string>() { "a b", "c%d", " ", "% % % %" ,"''","&","''","'"};
List<string> final = new List<string>();

Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[% &']+$");

foreach ( string str in liststr)
{
        if (! regex.IsMatch(str))
            final.Add(str);
}
```

Will give an output as

```
final = {"a b", "c%d"}
```